# Mediaelement flashfallback failing (MIME type not supported)

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, mime-types, mediaelement.js

I'm probably the millionth user suffering from this issue, but all fixes and guides online doesn't seem to solve this issue.

I'm using the [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) library for displaying .mp4 files on my website. As we all know, Firefox doesn't support .mp4 files in it's `<video>`-tag. So normally Mediaelement should do a Flash fallback. But it doesn't...

All I get is the well known error on screen and in console.

**Screen**
[image]

**Console**

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.somesite.com/some_file.mp4 failed.
```

I've added like a million MIMI types in my .htaccess, but this doesn't solve the issue.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg

AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
....
```

I have only the .mp4 files and for some reasons (project related), I cannot convert them into .webm or .ogg.

Other things you might want to know is that I'm using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) to run things local and I'm using Drupal. Although, I'm not sure this issue is Drupal related.

Am I missing something big here or how can I get this thing to work, because it's driving me nuts!